# Bash script convert none integer variable to integer

Tags: bash, numbers, jq

I have a bash script where I make a request like

```
GET "/_cat/indices?h=docs.count&format=json" | jq `.[]."docs.count"` 

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
response=($response)
IFS=$SAVEIFS

for (( i=0; i<${#response[@]}; i++ ))
do

echo "${response[$i]}"

done
```

The result I get is like the following:

```
"188"
"363"
"346224"
```

I would like to summarize these ones into one big number but I only get some kind of fault since they are not numbers. I have tried several different solutions I have found when I google but I do not succed to convert to integers (numbers).
My skills in bash are not that good. Does anyone have a solution for how I should do?

The IFS was something I found when I googled. Perhaps there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the double quotes?

Comment: What about running `jq` with `-r` or appending `| tonumber` to its code?

Comment: @choroba I mean that I would like to remove the double quotes and be able to summarize 188+363+34224 to a variable and only show the totalnumber instead. When I try with my low knowledge I do not succeed. How do you mean running jq with -r? I tried to add it in the code but does not succeed.

Comment: @choroba I added -r to my previous code    | jq '.[]."docs.count"'` ---> | jq -r '.[]."docs.count"'` and now I get without quotes. But when I try to add the numbers together I only get like 188+363+34224 and not the total sum instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `jq` to do the maths for you:

```
jq '[ .[].docs.count | tonumber ] | add'
```